# Overloading function with multiple template definitions not possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading

I tried this:

```
template<typename P, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<P>::value>>
void f(std::vector<P>* a) {
    // body for arithmetic P
}

template<typename P, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<P>::value>>
void f(std::vector<P>* a) {
    // body for class P
}
```

I thought it would overload `f` as the conditions are mutually exclusive, but found that it doesn't compile: "function template has already been defined".

What to do instead, if I want the function body of `f(std::vector<P>*)` to depend on whether `P` is arithmetic?

Comment: Look at common mistake of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) documentation on cppreference.com says:

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. This is illegal because **default template arguments are not part of function template's signature**, and declaring two different function templates with the same signature is illegal.

The examples on that same page show a similar situation as yours, and solve it by changing the template on one of the overloads, while maintaining the same signature for the functions themselves:

```cpp
// #4, enabled via a template parameter
template<class T,
         typename std::enable_if<
             !std::is_trivially_destructible<T>{} &&
             (std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_union<T>{}),
            int>::type = 0>
void destroy(T* t)
{
    std::cout << "destroying non-trivially destructible T\n";
    t->~T();
}

// #5, enabled via a template parameter
template<class T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value> >
void destroy(T* t) // note, function signature is unmodified
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < std::extent<T>::value; ++i) {
        destroy((*t)[i]);
    }
}
/*
template<class T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<T>::value> >
void destroy(T* t){} // error: has the same signature with #5
*/
```

So, you can do something similar in your code:

```
template<typename P, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<P>::value, int> = 0>
void f(std::vector<P>* a)
{
    // body for arithmetic P
}

template<typename P, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<P>::value>>
void f(std::vector<P>* a)
{
    // body for class P
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/tykuCK)

Answer (score 3):

Use tag dispatch, like this or similar:

```
void f_helper(std::vector<P>* a, std::true_type) {
    /* implementation for arithmetic type P */
}

void f_helper(std::vector<P>* a, std::false_type) {
    /* implementation for class type P */
}

void f(std::vector<P>* a) {
    return f_helper(a, std::is_arithmetic<P>{});
}
```

Comment: I would opt for more explicit tag names, which would allow for additional conditions to be added later on if needed: `struct IsArithmeticTag {}; struct IsClassTag {}; void f_helper(..., IsArithmeticTag) { ... } void f_helper(..., IsClassTag) { ... } void f(...) { f_helper(..., typename std::conditional<std::is_arithmetic<P>::value, IsArithmeticTag, IsClassTag>::type{}); }`  [Live Demo](https://ideone.com/51SOyi)