Downporting if constexpr to C++14
I'm trying to downport some C++17 code which uses if constexpr to C++14. The code looks like this:
template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T> || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string> ||
                std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, SVSTD::string_view> || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const char*> ||
                std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char*> || std::is_same_v<T, XLDateTime>>::type* = nullptr>

    XLCellValue(T value)    // NOLINT
    {
       // ===== If the argument is a bool, set the m_type attribute to Boolean.
       if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_same_v<T, bool>) {
           m_type  = XLValueType::Boolean;
           m_value = value;
       }

       // ===== If the argument is an integral type, set the m_type attribute to Integer.
       else if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<T, bool>) {
           m_type  = XLValueType::Integer;
           m_value = int64_t(value);
       }
    
    ....

I've done some research and found a similar question where people suggest using enable_if to imitate what if constexpr does. I've tried to do that and came up with the following translation of the code above:
template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_same<T, bool>::value>>
                                            
    XLCellValue(T value)    // NOLINT
    {
        // ===== If the argument is a bool, set the m_type attribute to Boolean.
        m_type  = XLValueType::Boolean;
        m_value = value;
    }

template<
    typename T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value>>
                                            
    XLCellValue(T value)    // NOLINT
    {
        // ===== If the argument is an integral type, set the m_type attribute to Integer.
        m_type  = XLValueType::Integer;
        m_value = int64_t(value);
    }

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile on a C++14 gcc. The compiler shows the following error:
struct std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_same<T, bool>::value is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

I've also tried to use template <class T, std::enable_if<...>> instead of template <typename T, ...> as described in the similar question linked above but it shows the same error.
Being a C++ noob, I'm stuck here. Can anybody help?

Typically when overloading a template using SFINAE you need to use the form typename std::enable_if< condition, some_type>::type = default_value_for_some_type.  link to why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749850/overloading-function-with-multiple-template-definitions-not-possible

Thanks, but what to use for some_type and default_value_for_some_type in my code above?

I typically use bool and true like typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value>, bool> = true

Ok, tried it. I also had to change enable_if to enable_if_t and I had to use template<class T, std::enable_if_t<...>> instead of template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<...>> and then it compiled. With these changes do you think it's guaranteed the code does the same as the C++17 code now?

GENERIC solution for replacing if constexpr in C++14 and constexpr if alternative

@Andreas Without a [mre] I can't really say.

@Andreas Yes, if you just copy paste the conditions then they will work in same way(except ofcourse from the inherent behavior of constexpr if and sfinae etc).

@NathanOliver It's not possible to tell from the code snippets I have posted in the OP?

Aha, now I understand the changes you had to make, I had a typo since I am so used to using the enable_if_t version.  The non-t version looks like typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value>, bool>::type = true.  And now that I see that it should be equivalent, minus the other types not included in the SFINAE.

But using template<typename T, std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, bool> = true> won't compile. It only compiles once I change it to template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value, bool> = true> So I have to use enable_if_t instead of enable_if and I have to use class T instead of typename T or it won't compile. I hope this is correct...

Clang backported it to C++11 https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#language-extensions-back-ported-to-previous-standards. MSVC backported it to C++14 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170#note_D
